# Limit a collaborator to only push to a specific branch

Tags: github

Is it possible to set up a collaborator to only pull/push from a specific branch. Or for that matter, not be able to make changes to Master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your repository belongs to an organization, you can enable branch restrictions settings and choose who can push to restricted branches.

https://help.github.com/articles/about-branch-restrictions/

https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/

Comment: thanks, but can you restrict a collaborator from even seeing certain branches?

Comment: You can restrict access to whole repository and then grant  privileges to certain branches.

Answer (score 2):

Revoke write access completely and make them fork the repository and submit pull requests.